# FTP File Copy to be triggered when the file is ready for reading in Mule?

Tags: mule

I am new to Mule, so let me say if this is a very basic question then please excuse me.

I am trying to copy a file (size: > 1GB) from one FTP Server(Source) to another FTP Server(Destination).

It takes 1 min to copy the file into the location at which my mule is polling.
As soon as i start copying the file on that location then itself my mule file copy is triggered and tries to read that file and fails as it is still is use by another process.

I wish to make a system in which the file copy is triggered not only when the the mule can detect a file at the Source, but i also want mule to wait for the file to be ready for reading and then start copying it. I don't want to insert a delay of fixed amount for this prupose.

Someone please suggest a method of doing it.

Comment: how do you know that the file is ready to be processed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that readiness is that there is no such kind of standardised flag in the filesystem. So the easier way of doing it is using the ´fileAge´ attribute of the [ftp connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/FTP+Transport+Reference), that is sadly EE only.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you move the file to the ftp directory Mule is pollong once is ready to be processed? That wouldn't require copying the file again, so it takes almost no time. Mule would pick it up only when is ready to be processed.